# Navigating to same screen builds two widget two times

Tags: flutter

I have an app, in home page products are displayed horizontally. Upon tapping product,  product details screen is shown where details about the products are shown in different widgets.

This detail screen also has horizontal scrolling list which shows related products. Upon tapping one of the related product, another instance of same detail screen is shown.

**Problem**

But problem here is build method is called twice. Its called twice only if I am trying to view details of related product (which are listed in product detail page itself.)

Here are some part of the code in `Details` screen.

```
class Details extends StatefulWidget {
  // Declare a field that holds the Todo.
  final details;

  // In the constructor, require a Todo.
  Details({Key key, @required this.details}) : super(key: key);

  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _DetailsState(details);
  }
}


class _DetailsState extends State<Details> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  _DetailsState(details);

  YoutubePlayerController _ytcontroller;

  TabController _tabController;
  int _tabIndex = 0;

  Screen size;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    if (_ytcontroller != null) {
      _ytcontroller.dispose();
    }

    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    if (widget.details.videos != null) {
      String videoId;
      videoId = YoutubePlayer.convertUrlToId(widget.details.videos[0].url);

      _ytcontroller = YoutubePlayerController(
        initialVideoId: videoId,
        flags: YoutubePlayerFlags(
          mute: false,
          autoPlay: true,
          disableDragSeek: false,
          loop: false,
          isLive: false,
          forceHideAnnotation: true,
        ),
      );
      _tabController = TabController(length: 4, vsync: this);
    } else {
      _tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
    }
    _tabController.addListener(_handleTabSelection);
  }

  _handleTabSelection() {
    if (_tabController.indexIsChanging) {
      setState(() {
        _tabIndex = _tabController.index;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String wid = widget.details.itemId;
    //IF I PUT DEBUG MARKER ABOVE AND TAP RELATED PRODUCT FROM PRODUCT DETAILS PAGE
    //THIS BUILD METHOD GETS CALLED TWO TIMES, 
    // FIRST => wid = item id of clicked product 
    // SECOND => wid = item id of currently viewing product 

    size = Screen(MediaQuery.of(context).size);
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      backgroundColor: Constants.scaffoldColor,
      floatingActionButton: buildBoomMenu(widget.details),
      body: NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              expandedHeight: size.getSizePx(277),
              floating: false,
              title: const Text("Details"),
              pinned: true,
              flexibleSpace: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                      begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                      end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                      colors: [Constants.gradientStart, Constants.gradientEnd]),
                ),
                child: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                  centerTitle: true,
                  background: Swiper(
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return _cacheImageBuilder(
                          widget.details.images[index].thumb);
                    },
                    itemCount: widget.details.images.length,
                    pagination: new SwiperPagination(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      builder: FractionPaginationBuilder(
                        activeColor: Colors.white,
                        color: Colors.white70,
                        fontSize: size.getSizePx(16),
                        activeFontSize: size.getSizePx(20),
                      ),
                    ),
                    autoplay: true,
                    onTap: (index) {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => ImageViewer(
                            imglists: widget.details.images,
                            initialIndex: index,
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    autoplayDelay: 8000,
                    autoplayDisableOnInteraction: true,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ];
        },
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              left: size.getSizePx(10), right: size.getSizePx(10)),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                //height: size.getSizePx(230),
                child: propertyDetails(),
              ),
              TabBar(
                controller: _tabController,
                labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: size.getSizePx(12)),
                labelColor: Constants.primaryColor,
                unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black45,
                indicatorColor: Constants.primaryColor,
                tabs: [
                  Tab(
                    text: "Seller Info",
                    icon: Icon(Constants.iconAccount),
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    text: "Details",
                    icon: Icon(Constants.iconDetails),
                  ),
                  Tab(text: "Video", icon: Icon(Constants.iconYoutube)),
                ],
              ),
              Container(
                child: [
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: size.getSizePx(15)),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        //Show some widgets
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: size.getSizePx(15)),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        //show few widgets here
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                   //show videos
                  ),
                ][_tabIndex],
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              RelatedProducts( //Another widget which fetches list of products related to product whose detail we are currently viewing
                deviceType: "mobile",
                model: widget.details.model,
                sku: widget.details.sku,
                category: widget.details.category,
                itemId: widget.details.itemId,
                brand: widget.details.brand,
              ),
              SizedBox(height: size.getSizePx(40)),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: That's the expected behavior. What's wrong?

Comment: @RémiRousselet Actually, when I get back from detail of  `Related product` i tapped, the related products of  original product I was viewing changes to that of what I had in detail of related product.

Answer (score 0):

build method is called evreytime the state changes (includes navigation), but as i can see you are trying to get screen size evreytime in build method, i'v created this library that could be may be helpful for you [responsive_flutter](https://github.com/layounisl/responsive_flutter).